# Números romanos maiúsculo com ucwords() ou ucfirst()

Tags: php, regex

Enquanto digitava esta pergunta eu modificava algumas coisas, o que me fez conseguir solucionar o problema. Por isso estou criando este "compartilhe o conhecimento" caso alguém venha a ter o mesmo problema.

Suponha o seguinte nomes:

1. Assassin's Creed III
2. ASSASSIN'S CREED IV: BLACK FLAG

### Problema:

Para torna-lo padrão (e reduzir espaço, porque letras maiúsculas são maiores quanto exibidas), eu utilizo isso:

```
$nome = ucwords( strtolower( $fonte['Nome'] ) );
```

> **Resultado:**

1. Assassin's Creed Iii
2. Assassin's Creed Iv: Black Flag

O resultado está correto para a função.

> **O que desejo:**

1. Assassin's Creed *III*
2. Assassin's Creed *IV*: Black Flag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Com a finalidade de conseguir apenas manter (ou tornar) os numerais romanos em maiúsculo criei isto, adaptando de algumas pesquisas.

### Solução:

```
<?php
$explodes = explode(' ', strtolower( $fonte['Nome'] ) );
// Isso irá forçar tudo para minusculo, afim de entrar no regex e quebrar os espaços.

foreach($explodes as $explode){
// Cria loop finito para cada palavra

   if(!preg_match("/^m{0,4}(cm|cd|d?c{0,3})(xc|xl|l?x{0,3})(ix|iv|v?i{0,3})(.?)$/", $explode)){
        $palavra .= ucfirst($explode).' ';
        // Se não houver número romano a primeira letra é passada para maiúsculo.
   }else{
        $palavra .= strtoupper($explode).' ';
       // Se houver número romano tudo é passado para maiúsculo.
   }

}

echo rtrim($palavra, ' ');
// Remove ultimo espaço inserido e exibe.
?>
```

> **Resultado:**

1. Assassin's Creed III
2. Assassin's Creed IV: Black Flag

> **Demais testes:**

1. `grand theft auto v`  > `Grand Theft Auto V`
2. `final fantasy xv`  > `Final Fantasy XV`
3. `final Fantasy Xiii`  > `Final Fantasy XIII`
4. `FINAL FANTASY® XIV: A Realm Reborn` > `Final Fantasy® XIV: A Realm Reborn`

### Função:

Para quem quiser utilizar mais fácil:

```
function nucword($frase){   
$explodes = explode(' ', strtolower($frase) );
$palavra = '';

foreach($explodes as $explode){ 
   if(!preg_match("/^m{0,4}(cm|cd|d?c{0,3})(xc|xl|l?x{0,3})(ix|iv|v?i{0,3})(.?)$/", $explode)){
        $palavra .= ucfirst($explode).' ';
   }else{
        $palavra .= strtoupper($explode).' ';
   }    
}

return rtrim($palavra, ' ');
}
```

Utilize:

```
nucword('sua frase Ii');
// Sua Frase II
```

Exemplo:

```
echo nucword('grand theft auto v');
// Grand Theft Auto V
```

Comment: Tem muita RegEx mal usada no site, mas para esta resposta, RegEx serve muito bem. Esse é um exemplo bom da complexidade adequada pra justificar o uso.